# How to fix OPTIONS 401 unauthorised error in spring rest and ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am trying to make a get request for an api which is in sprint mvc rest, I get the below error in the console:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/api/users/travel-plan/1 401 (Unauthorized)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/users/travel-plan/1' from origin 'http://localhost:8585' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Below is the code for the ajax request:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/users/travel-plan/1',{
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                Authorization: 'Basic' + btoa('xlz@wwe.com' + ":" + 'thepass')
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Please refer the code below for the controller:

```
package com.travelplanner.rest.controller;
//COPY
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.travelplanner.rest.entity.UserDetails;
import com.travelplanner.rest.entity.TravelPlans;
import com.travelplanner.rest.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    private boolean doesUserExist(String username) {
        boolean exists = userDetailsManager.userExists(username);

        return exists;
    }

//  API to add user
    @PostMapping("/user/register")
    public UserDetails addUser(@RequestBody UserDetails userDetails) {
        if(!doesUserExist(userDetails.getEmail())) {
            String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(userDetails.getPassword());
            encodedPassword="{bcrypt}"+encodedPassword;
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
            User user = new User(userDetails.getEmail(), encodedPassword, authorities);
            userDetailsManager.createUser(user);
            userDetails.setId(0);
            userService.saveUser(userDetails);
            return userDetails;
        }else {
            return null;
        }

    }

//  API to get user/login
    @PostMapping("/users/{email}")
    public UserDetails authUser(@PathVariable String email) {
        return userService.getUser(email);
    }

//  API to add travel plan
    @PostMapping("/users/travel-plan/{userId}")
    public TravelPlans addTravelPlan(@RequestBody TravelPlans travelPlan, @PathVariable int userId) {
        userService.saveTravelPlan(travelPlan, userId);
        return travelPlan;
    }

//  API to update travel plan
    @PutMapping("/users/travel-plan/{userId}")
    public TravelPlans updateTravelPlan(@RequestBody TravelPlans travelPlan, @PathVariable int userId) {
        userService.updateTravelPlan(travelPlan, userId);
        return travelPlan; 
    }

//  API to get travel plans
    @GetMapping("/users/travel-plan/{userId}")
    public List<TravelPlans> getTravelPlans(@PathVariable int userId) {
        return userService.getTravelPlans(userId);
    }

//  API to delete travel plan
    @DeleteMapping("/users/travel-plan/{planId}")
    public String deleteTravelPlan(@PathVariable int planId) {
        userService.deleteTravelPlan(planId);  
        return "Deleted the travel plan with id: " + planId;
    }
}
```

I have tried adding the `@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost8585")` and also tried putting `.cors().disable` at the beginning and end of the `http` trail in the config.java but nothing seemed to work. I still get the above message in the console.

Please refer the ode below for the congfig.java:

```
package com.travelplanner.rest.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.travelplanner.rest")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {

        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // set the jdbc driver
        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");       
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }

        // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are reading the data
        logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));

        // set database connection props
        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        // set connection pool props
        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));     
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return myDataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        return props;               
    }


    // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int

    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {

        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

        return intPropVal;
    }   

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");;
    }

}
```

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your controller and WebMvcConfigurer  code in your question

Comment: @GovindParashar I have added the code for the controller and the WebMvcConfigurer.

Comment: Do you want Global CORS Configuration ?

Comment: Yes Sir! I am looking for Global CORS Configuration.

Comment: If you are using chrome then please run with --disable-web-security

Comment: @GovindParashar Yes but it will be only till development. I want to configure it from the spring instead and I have tried all the ways possible and no resolution yet. Also, my frontend from where the calls are made is going to be deployed elsewhere and not on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its work for me with:

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
```

Comment: It did not work with the above method for me instead I got rid of the cross origin error with http.cors().and().... However, now I get: GET http://localhost:8080/api/users/travel-plan/1 401 (Unauthorized)